# Can an AppProject role grant access to another ArgoCD project?

Tags: argocd

I'm running ArgoCD v2.9. Is it possible to grant access to another project resources in an AppProject role?

Example:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: AppProject
metadata:
  name: myproject
spec:
  roles:
    - name: read
      groups:
        - READ
      policies:
        - p, proj:myproject:read, applications, get, myproject/*, allow
        - p, proj:myproject:read, applications, get, default/*, allow
    - name: mod
      groups:
        - MOD
      policies:
        - p, proj:myproject:mod, applications, *, myproject/*, allow
        - p, proj:myproject:mod, applications, *, default/*, allow
```

In my testing the users in READ and MOD groups were able to see only the Applications under `myproject`. The `default` project Applications were not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself with the solution after a night's sleep:

You can't grant access from one AppProject to another. The correct way is to grant the access to eg. AppProject `default` *in the AppProject `default`*. So if I want the group READ to see both `myproject` and `default`, I grant access in both AppProjects.